# How do I hide Android's bottom action bar in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-actionbar, flutter-layout

I know it can be hidden with the following code.

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

But as soon as I tap on the screen, the bottom action bar appears again.
How can I solve this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in flutter; Nothing we can do for now:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62412

Solution might be to hide both status bar and navigation bar

`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])`

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no way to hide it directly in Flutter. But you can do this by calling a native Android method, which I've already tried and verified works.

```
private fun fullScreenCall() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT in 12..18) { // lower api
            val v: View = this.window.decorView
            v.systemUiVisibility = View.GONE
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            //for new api versions.
            val decorView: View = window.decorView
            val uiOptions: Int = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = uiOptions
        }
    }
```